# Python conversion from c_double to float

Tags: python, ctypes

I am new to Python. I would like to know what would be the best way to convert a c_double (from ctypes) to a float. My code is working, but I would like to know if there is a pythonic way to do it. What I currently do is:

```
FloatValue = float( str(d_Val)[9:( len( str(d_Val) ) )-1] )
```

Where `d_Val` is `c_double(-10.0)`, and I want to keep `-10.0`
Working with Python 2.7 under windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `value` property on a `c_double`.

```
>>> ctypes.c_double(-10.0).value
-10.0
```